# передача словаря js post

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему метод post  не передает данные словаря

console.log(allData); отрабатывает и выводит в консоль словарь вложенный
$.post('../listener.php', allData); пишет undefined

словарь вложенный, в нем еще 1 словарь и внутри еще один
 когда объявляю словарь [] работает .shift(); но есть в словаре атрибут lenght если объявить через {} все отправляется но из таблицы цепляется 1 строка что не нужно

```
var allData = [];

var AllTable = $("Table");

AllTable.each(function(rows, Ctable){
    TableData = [];
    if  ($(Ctable).find("th").length <5){

    }else{
        $(Ctable).find('tr').each(function(row, tr){
          TableData[row]={
            "id" : test($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').attr("id"))
            , "from" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            , "till" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            , "where" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "who" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
          }
        }); 
        TableData.shift();  
    };
    allData[rows]=TableData;
});

console.log(allData);
$.post('../listener.php', allData);
```

Comment: Вы отправляете на сервер "словарь" (объект), где вы получаете `undefined`? На сервере?

Comment: да на сервере. var allData = []; при таком объявлении не работает. var allData = {}; при таком объявлении работает. в консоли отличие при 1 объявлении идет аргумент lenght, а при {} его нет. но и не работает функция TableData.shift(); которая удаляет 1 строку в словаре

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите код с примером того что у вас в `allData`

Comment: var allData = {};

var AllTable = $("Table");

AllTable.each(function(rows, Ctable){
 TableData = {};
 if  ($(Ctable).find("th").length <5){
  
 }else{
  $(Ctable).find('tr').each(function(row, tr){
  TableData[row]={
   "id" : test($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').attr("id"))
   , "from" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
   , "till" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
   , "where" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
   , "who" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
  }
 }); 
 TableData.shift();  
 };
 allData[rows]=TableData;
});

console.log(allData);
$.post('../listener.php', allData);

Comment: в отладчике при отправке undefined: на сервере соответственно то же.
print_r($_POST);

Comment: "$.post('../listener.php', allData); пишет undefined" - что это значит?

Comment: в chrome отладчике network->header>-form-data

Comment: В параметры пост запроса надо передавать объект. Попробуйте так `$.post('../listener.php', { dictionary: allData });` ну и на сервере естественно это надо учесть.

Comment: { dictionary: allData } да, так сработало